# Cómo puedo imprimir la primera ocurrencia de un .txt en Python?

Tags: python, text

Estoy intentando realizar una extracción de datos de un fichero .txt en Python. Mi objetivo es capturar la última ocurrencia de una determinada palabra y mostrar la siguiente línea, por lo que hago un reverse() del texto y leo desde atrás. En este caso, busco la palabra 'MEC', y mostrar la siguiente línea, pero capturo todas las ocurrencias de la palabra, no la primera. Les dejo mi código:

```py
import re

from file_read_backwards import FileReadBackwards

with FileReadBackwards("camdex.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for l in file:
        lines = l

#with open('camdex.txt', 'r') as file:
        line = file.readline()
        while line:
            if re.match('MEC', line):
                x = (file.readline())
                x2 = (x.strip('\n'))
                print(x2)

            line = file.readline()
```

El texto es el siguiente:

```
MEC
29/35

MEC
28,29/35
```

La salida que obtengo es la siguiente:

```
28,29/35
29/35
```

Y finalmente, lo que quiero es capturar sólo la primera:

```
28,29/35
```

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución consiste en detener el ciclo `while` que revisa las lineas cuando encuentre la primera ocurrencia, para así evitar que siga buscando. Esto se puede lograr de la siguiente manera:

```
import re

from file_read_backwards import FileReadBackwards

with FileReadBackwards("camdex.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    line = file.readline()
    while line:
        if re.match('MEC', line):
            x = (file.readline())
            x2 = (x.strip('\n'))
            print(x2)
            break    
        line = file.readline()
```

Espero haber solucionado tu problema. Cualquier otro comentario estaré atento.

Comment: Solucionado, muchisimas gracias!